# Get order as per click on checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of checkboxes:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="check5" value="5" rel="<p>Vatican visit</p>">
        </td>
        <td>Visit to Rome</td>
        <td>Vatican visit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="check7" value="7" rel="<p>visit church</p>">
        </td>
        <td>Visit church</td>
        <td>visit church</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="check11" value="11" rel="<p><strong>A round trip across the city highlights</strong></p>">
        </td>
        <td>Paris tour</td>
        <td>A round trip across the city highlights</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="check12" value="12" rel="<ul><li>Have <strong>fun with children's</strong> dearest cartoon charecters</li></ul>">
        </td>
        <td>Disney land vist</td>
        <td>Have fun with children's dearest cartoon charecters</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What my need is i would like to get the values in rel according to the order of checking

Now im using following jquery

```
$('.check_class:checked').each(function() {
    var details = $(this).attr('rel');
    final_details += details;
    final_details += ",<br>";
});
```

It works but it working like 
if i choosed "paris tour" as my first click and then "visit church" it returns values in which first one will be  "visit church" and then "paris tour"

What my requirement is i need those values as per the click on checkbox, as with the before example i need "paris tour" as first and then "visit church"

Im expecting a real help on this

Comment: That's an invalid HTML you got there. You need to encode your `<p>` inside `rel` attributes

Comment: im talking about the value that i will got in final_details,

Comment: To get it in order, you have to track the order; there's nothing in the DOM that will do it for you (the DOM is always in document order). So for instance, update `final_details` *on click*.

Comment: You can create an array to hold all selected ids and then use `splice` and `push` to remove and add selected values. In the end the order in the array will reflect the order the items were clicked.

Comment: Updated my answer that will handle removal now as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/1pgqx4pt/17/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myOptions = [];

    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var option = {};
        option['id'] =  $(this).attr('id');
        option['rel'] =  $(this).attr('rel');

        if (this.checked)
           myOptions.push(option);
        else
           myOptions = $.grep(myOptions, function(o){ return o.id != option['id']; });

      console.log(myOptions);
    });
});
```

Here in the below codes you are looping DOM element as per checked state so that will create the array as per DOM order.

```
$('.check_class:checked').each(function() {
    var details = $(this).attr('rel');
    final_details += details;
    final_details += ",<br>";
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer that will handle removal now as well.

Comment: from this how could i set the value in rel to final_details

Comment: Means..I'm not getting you! Can you please explain?

Comment: i have mentioned my requirement,i have included some values in rel of each checkboxes.I need those values in "final_details" as per the order of clicked

Comment: Sorry im not getting it by using this method

Comment: What you are not getting men! Did you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/1pgqx4pt/19/) link! As per this when you click on check box you get your result in `final_details` variable. Do whatever you want with that!

Comment: OK. I already mentioned this link in my previous comment. Check the 5th comment! Anyways it's works for you now, please accept the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95024/discussion-between-freelance-phinix-and-deepak-biswal).